# C# RealProxy: generic methods?

Tags: c#, reflection, generics, realproxy

I'm trying to handle a call of a generic method through a `RealProxy`, but I cannot seem to find the information about the actual type of the generic parameter used in the intercepted method call. An excerpt of the code:

```
    public override IMessage Invoke(IMessage msg)
    {
        ...
        string methodName = (string)msg.Properties["__MethodName"];
        Type[] parameterTypes = (Type[])msg.Properties["__MethodSignature"];
        object[] args = (object[])msg.Properties["__Args"];

        MethodInfo method = typeToProxy.GetMethod(methodName, parameterTypes);
        ...
```

Let's say I'm proxying an interface like

```
interface IFactory
{
   TService Create<TService>()
}
```

When I call the proxy

```
proxied.Create<MyClass>()
```

I want to be able to find out the generic parameter is of type `MyClass`. Is this possible through `RealProxy`?

Comment: It is possible through reflection to query for generic types.

Comment: Trying to find out the exact generic class somewhat defeats the purpose of having a generic class. Why do you need to know the class?

Comment: @Albin, I'm writing a factory method proxy for a dependency injection framework I'm working on. Something like Windsor's typed factory facility (http://kozmic.pl/archive/2009/12/24/castle-typed-factory-facility-reborn.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an excellent [MSDN article](https://web.archive.org/web/20130429155515/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164085.aspx) about RealProxy which I recommend you read.
Among other things, it introduces `MethodCallMessageWrapper` which saves you the trouble of working directly against the `Properties` dictionary. From the latter you can get the `MethodBase`, which in turn contains the generic arguments:

```
internal class MyProxy : RealProxy
{
   private object m_instance;    
   private MyProxy( object instance ) : base( typeof( IFactory) )
   {
      m_instance = instance;
   }

  public override IMessage Invoke( IMessage message )
  {
     IMethodCallMessage methodMessage =
        new MethodCallMessageWrapper( (IMethodCallMessage) message );

     // Obtain the actual method definition that is being called.
     MethodBase method = methodMessage.MethodBase;

     Type[] genericArgs = method.GetGenericArguments(); //This is what you want

     return new ReturnMessage(...);
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: No problem! I still recommend you read the article though, it's really good

Comment: Too bad the link is broken!

Comment: @Guge thanks for spotting, replaced with wayback machine link

Answer (score 3):

For method calls, the `IMessage` argument should be a `IMethodMessage`, which has a `MethodBase` property:

```
public override IMessage Invoke(IMessage message)
{
    IMethodMessage methodMessage = message as IMethodMessage;
    if (methodMessage != null)
    {
         MethodBase method = methodMessage.MethodBase;
         Type[] genericArgs = method.GetGenericArguments();

         ...
    }
    else
    {
        // not a method call
    }
}
```

Comment: Ruben, I tested your code and it works, thanks, +1. I'm sorry I could not accept both answers.

Comment: Since `IMethodCallMessage` implements `IMethodMessage`, and `MethodCallMessageWrapper` is a simple wrapper for `IMethodCallMessage`, both our answers boil down to pretty much the same code